# Azure function queue trigger distributed tracing

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, azure-storage-queues, dotnet-isolated

I have a .NET isolated function with a queue trigger.

When triggering that queue from the storage explorer or from another function using a `QueueServiceClient`, a new `operationId` is made up. Thus I cannot correlate it, it seems.

Is it possible to do distributed tracing using W3C standard for Azure Function Queue trigger? I can not find any source on this.

If so, how?

Comment: can you provide some more information so that community will help to solve your query.

Comment: @DelliganeshSevanesan I will find some time to create a minimal example. But the gist of the question is how to enable e2e tracing following W3C Trace Context specification on Queue Triggered Functions. I will provide an example soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently not supported.
Azure Functions team will evaluate this scenario (at some unmentioned point in time) whether or not it can be/will be supported. This has to do with their dependency on the team creating the `Azure.Storage.Queues` SDK.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/1126